# create AWS IAM Policy using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role(MyIAMrole) which has already been created. I want to attach a policy to this role using a Cloudformation template.

```
"Mypolicy":{
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "assume-role-policy",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
        { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", "Resource": "*" }
      ]
    },
    "Roles": [ { "Ref": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/MyIAMrole" } ]
  }
}
```

When I try to validate this I am getting an error saying "Unreolved reference options".

How to attach this policy to an already existing role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get your code snippet to work by referring to the **Name** of a role rather than the ARN.

As per the [`AWS::IAM::Policy` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-roles):

> **Roles:** The **names** of AWS::IAM::Roles to which this policy will be attached.

However, while the stack went to CREATE_COMPLETE, I couldn't see the policy listed in the Policies section of IAM, nor could I see the policy attached to the referenced role.

It *might* be that you cannot use CloudFormation to attach a policy to an existing role. You might need to create the Role as part of the CloudFormation template to be able to attach a role.

Comment: How did you validate the template with just providing the name? I am having issues even there.[From this link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-template-validation/), it syas that "Resource logical IDs exist or are defined in your template, or physical IDs of resources in your environment exist". So which means if i provide the physical ID it should work right?

Comment: The documentation (as shown in my answer) says that **Roles** wants the **names** of the roles. I didn't run validate -- I put it in an actual stack and ran it.

Comment: I was able to use the role name and attach it to the existing role

Comment: Hi @vkr, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein!  FWIW - I was also able to attach a policy to an existing role in a Beanstalk resource here: https://github.com/russau/renew-certs-flask/blob/master/.ebextensions/01_setup.config#L11